# Dockerized React.js app only serving root page

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, vite

I dockerised a react.js app deployed using vite and nginx.

When I test on localhost on my PC deployed on port 5173 the root page is only available. So `http:localhost:5173` works fine to show the homepage of my application. However, when I try another url such as `http:localhost:5173/about` I get 404 Not Found Error.

When I `exec` into the react container on docker and go to the dir `/usr/share/nginx/html` I get the following:

```
50x.html    assets      index.html  speedtest
```

Dockerfile for react and nginx:

```
#### Stage 1: Build the angular application
FROM node as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY client/package*.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY client/ /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

#### Stage 2: serve the react application from Nginx for production environment
FROM nginx:1.21.4-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY client/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx","-g", "daemon off;"]
```

my `nginx.conf`

```
upstream backend {
    server internet-speed-backend:8080;
  }

server {

  listen 80;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;
  
  location @proxy-backend {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  
  }
}
```

My vite config file:

```
import {resolve} from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

const root = resolve(__dirname, 'src')
const outDir = resolve(__dirname, 'dist')

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  root,
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir,
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(root, 'index.html'),
        speedtest: resolve(root, 'speedtest', 'speedtest.html')
      }

    }
  }


})
```

project structure:

```
    ── dist
    │   ├── assets
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── speedtest
    │       └── speedtest.html
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── nginx.conf
    ├── package.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── public
    ├── src
    │   ├── App.jsx
    │   ├── assets
    │   ├── components
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── main.jsx
    │   ├── routes
    │   │   ├── About.jsx
    │   │   ├── Home.jsx
    │   │   ├── Login.jsx
    │   │   ├── Signup.jsx
    │   │   ├── UserData.jsx
    │   │   └── UserDataRow.jsx
    │   ├── services
    │   └── speedtest
    ├── vite.config.js
    └── yarn.lock
```

Comment: What config are you giving Nginx to enable push-state routing, so that client-side "pages" fall back to `index.html` (see e.g. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)?

Comment: I am pretty knew to nginx. I natively thought the docker commands set out in the dockerfile above in combination with my custom `nginx.conf` file (added above now for reference) would do everything to serve all my react routes. Grateful if you could take a look and help. Thank you

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? Does the about.html file live in the same directory as the index file? There could be a few things going on but its hard to diagnose without knowing what the project looks like as npm and docker can be very particular when building the app and the image.

Comment: @NateHastings project structure added above. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This is the setup I use in most of my application, have a look and let me known:

**.nginx.conf**

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_types
      application/atom+xml
      application/geo+json
      application/javascript
      application/x-javascript
      application/json
      application/ld+json
      application/manifest+json
      application/rdf+xml
      application/rss+xml
      application/xhtml+xml
      application/xml
      font/eot
      font/otf
      font/ttf
      image/svg+xml
      text/css
      text/javascript
      text/plain
      text/xml;


    add_header Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-corp";
    add_header Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "same-origin";

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Comment: That config didn't work for me.